# How to decode a raw transaction in Python? (superfluous bytes error)

Tags: transactions, bytecode, rlp, hex

I have a raw_tx in hex format. I'm using the following code to convert it from hexstr to a readable JSON text format. The issue is that I'm receiving the following error for certain transactions: DecodingError: RLP string ends with 9144 superfluous bytes

> import rlp
> from eth_typing import HexStr -
> from eth_utils import to_bytes -
> from ethereum.transactions import Transaction

```
def hex_to_bytes(data: str) -> bytes:
    return to_bytes(hexstr=HexStr(data))

txs = rlp.decode(hex_to_bytes(hexstr), Transaction)
txs.to_dict()
```

hexstr is equal to:

> "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"

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and managed to use the eth_account package with success.

```
from eth_account._utils.typed_transactions import (TypedTransaction)
from hexbytes import HexBytes

print(TypedTransaction.from_bytes(HexBytes(tx_raw)).as_dict())
```